# Need to transform a unix into a date but some values are already in a date format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field that is being pushed into my database where 90% of the values are a  millisecond-unix timestamp but a about 5% of the values are null and 5% are actual date stamps but the field is a text field.

I am trying to convert the date using this:

```
cast(to_timestamp(cast(date_field as bigint)/1000) as date)
```

The problem is that the date fields that are already timestamps (in a text field format) are messing me up since they can't be converted to bigint. All of the values like this start with "2016-" so I made a query to exclude them but they are still there.

The query to exclude these:

```
Select distinct
date
from table1
where date<>'2016%'
```

One of the result values:

```
2016-11-04 02:23:10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can convert the time in milliseconds like a date:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t.date/1000,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') FROM table1 t WHERE t.date NOT LIKE '2016-%' AND t.date IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do 
something like:

```
where date like '20%' --for years after 2000 (there isnt yet a unix timestimp that starts with 2 )
or date like '19%' (there isnt yet a unix timestimp that starts with 19 )
```

Comment: my problem is that I am attempting to use filters like this but they are not working. where date='20%' and where date<>'20%'  both filter nothing even though I see the values right there when the results are displayed.

Comment: Use 'like' or 'not like' instead, you can use '%' only with like statement